# $n$th root of unity over any field is isomorphic to $Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Over any field whose characteristic doesn't divides $n$.

Is group of $n$th root of unity is isomorphic to $Z_n$?

Comment: Have you tried constructing a map between the two sets?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Let $K = \mathbf{Q}$. The only fourth roots of unity in here are $\{\pm 1\}$, but $\mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}$ has size four.

Comment: However, there is a salvage. Here is the general lemma (exercise): Any finite subgroup of a field is cyclic.

Comment: If the field is complex  I am done by mapping generators. But in arbitrary field I don't know the structure of n th root of unity

Comment: @babu_babu can we at least say it's cyclic

Comment: @LordShadow, yes that is the content of the exercise I gave you. I don't think it's that easy of an exercise, but it is easy to google.

Comment: Z/4Z is not field

Comment: @LordShadow, your claim is that the group of $4$-th roots of unity is isomorphic to $\BZ/4\BZ$. I showed explicitly that such an isomorphism cannot be true, because there are only 2 roots of unity, but $\BZ/4\BZ$ has size 4, and isomorphisms of groups are bijections. This has nothing to do with $\BZ/4\BZ$ being a field. The exercise I gave is relevant because the $n$-th roots of unity inside $K$ are a finite subgroup.

Comment: Okay okay now I got it. Multiplicative group of field is  cyclic.  Great . Thanks

Comment: Any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic. If your field has all the $n$th roots of unity, say if it is algebraically closed, then you can say nth roots of unity is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: @Ignorant Mathematician How do we primitive n th root of unity exists in algebraic  closure of K?

Comment: Algebraically closed fields will have all roots of $X^n-1$

Comment: @ignorant mathematician  Yes but is only has primitive nth root iff $x^n-1$ is seperable  which happen if  char K does not divides . If Char K divides n , then what to do

Comment: In that case just ignore the prime power of $p$ dividing $n$ where $p=char \ K$

Comment: Could you please explain  your last comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112208/discussion-between-lord-shadow-and-ignorant-mathematician).